# Select combination of elements from array whose sum is smallest possible positive number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, selection, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have an array of `M` elements, all numbers, negative or positive or zero.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm to select `N` elements from the array, such that the sum of these `N` elements is the smallest possible positive number?

Take this array for example:

```
-1000,-700,-400,-200,-100,-50,10,100,300,600,800,1200
```

Now I have to select any 5 elements such that their sum is the smallest possible positive number.

Comment: can you please add more information? What are the limits for N, M and the numbers?

Comment: no you did not add any constraints. I need to know what are the maximum allowed values of N, M and the numbers so that I know what is the needed computational complexity of the solution.

Comment: Not much, within easy computational range, take for example, N and M cannot exceed 10000. That is also on a higher limit.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you saying that the numbers can be randomly selected from the array, or they need to be a contiguous sub-array. What is the upper limit for the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: They can be randomly selected, there is no check on complexity of the algo as of now.

Comment: @Ash I agree this would be a whole lot more interesting if there were some upper limit on the complexity, or we had to find the most efficient way!

Comment: Are you interested in algorithms with possibly suboptimal results, but much better time complexity?

Comment: would the array elements always be distinct?

Comment: Sounds similar to the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: (1) We need the complexity as low as possible, this complete logic has to be implemented in a financial system while making payments and grouping credit memos i.e. negative invoice and positive invoices, keep a max invoice number, so that most number of credit memos are used to do payment, keep the sum positive for the final payment. The invoices can go upto more than 1 lac in a single payment.

(2) No the array elements can be repetitive.

(3) Yes, I would be happy with an algo which provides sub optimal solution with better time complexity.

Comment: Well what I thought of was to take 2 arrays and put positives in one and negatives in another. Sort both in desc order in each array.

Pick first positive number which would be the biggest number and add it with first negative number which would be biggest number in absolute value for negatives.

If sum is positive, add negative, else positive, repeat.

In the end, it might be required to remove a negative number bcos a positive sum cannot be attained, I want a solution with better time complexity than this !

Comment: I updated my suboptimal solution...check it out if you like... although it may not be as formally optimal and efficient as integer programming..

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I updated my answer to use terminology consistent with your question.

Answer (score 7):

## Formulation

For `i = 1, ..., M`:

- Let `a_i` be the `i`th number in your list of candidates
- Let `x_i` denote whether the `i`th number is included in your set of `N` chosen numbers

Then you want to solve the following integer programming problem.

```
minimize: sum(a_i * x_i)
with respect to: x_i
subject to:
    (1) sum(a_i * x_i) >= 0
    (2) sum(x_i) = N
    (3) x_i in {0, 1}
```

You can apply an integer program solver "out of the box" to this problem to find the optimal solution or a suboptimal solution with controllable precision.

## Resources

- [Integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)
- [Explanation of branch-and-bound integer program solver](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor4600.S07/bb-lecb.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [Kadane’s Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) would do the trick, although it is for the maximum sum but I have also implemented it to find the minimum sum, though can't find the code right now.

Comment: I don't think so. Here you  may need to first increase and then decrease the accumulated sum,

Comment: True, the largest sum cannot be turned into least positive sum that way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the best possible solution, you can simply use brute force ie. try all posible combinations of fiwe numbers.

Something like this very quick and dirty algorithm:

```
public List<Integer> findLeastPositivSum(List<Integer> numbers) {
    List<Integer> result;
    Integer resultSum;
    List<Integer> subresult, subresult2, subresult3, subresult4, subresult5;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 4; i++) {
        subresult = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        subresult.add(numbers.get(i));
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size() - 3; j++) {
            subresult2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(subresult);
            subresult2.add(j);
            for (int k = j + 1; k < numbers.size() - 2; k++) {
                subresult3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(subresult2);
                subresult3.add(k);
                for (int l = k + 1; l < numbers.size() - 1; l++) {
                    subresult4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(subresult3);
                    subresult4.add(k);
                    for (int m = l + 1; m < numbers.size(); m++) {
                        subresult5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(subresult4);
                        subresult5.add(k);
                        Integer subresultSum = sum(subresult5);
                        if (subresultSum > 0) {
                            if (result == null || resultSum > subresultSum) {
                                result = subresult;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public Integer sum(List<Integer> list) {
    Integer result = 0;
    for (Integer integer : list) {
        result += integer;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is really quick and dirty algorithm, it can be done more elegantly. I can provide cleaner algorithm e.g. using recursion.

It can be also further optimized. E.g. you can remove similar numbers from input list as first step.

Comment: Sounds good, but when the size would be near 10K elements, out of 9K have to picked up, this would kill the time :)

Comment: Of course this is bruteforce algorithm with exponential complexity. There is faster algorithm but it will probably give suboptimal results, but it would be much faster. Are you interested in algorithms with possibly suboptimal results?

Comment: Yes, I would be happy with an algo which provides sub optimal solution with better time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Let initial array be shorted already, or i guess this will work even when it isnt shorted..
N -> Length of array
M -> Element req.
R[] -> Answer
TEMP[] -> For calculations
minSum -> minSum
A[] -> Initial input

All above variables are globally defined

```
int find(int A[],int start,int left)
{
    if(left=0)
    {
        //sum elements in TEMP[] and save it as curSum
        if(curSum<minSum)
        {
        minSum=curSum;
        //assign elements from TEMP[] to R[] (i.e. our answer)      
        }
    }

    for(i=start;i<=(N-left);i++)
    {
        if(left==M)
            curSum=0;
        TEMP[left-1]=A[i];
        find(A[],i+1,left-1);
    }
}
```

// Made it in hurry so maybe some error would be existing..

Working solution on ideone :
http://ideone.com/YN8PeW

Comment: Now available on ideone.com with proper program : http://ideone.com/YN8PeW...
     
Answer to your test case from my program : 
800 600 10 -400 -1000
:)

Hope this will make this question as solved for sure..

Comment: Well, this is a brute force, won't help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something sub optimal in Haskell, which (as with many of my ideas) could probably be further and better optimized. It goes something like this:

1. Sort the array (I got interesting results by trying both ascending and descending)
2. B N = first N elements of the array
3. B (i), for i > N = best candidate; where (assuming integers) if they are both less than 1, the candidates are compared by the absolute value of their sums; if they are both 1 or greater, by their sums; and if only one candidate is greater than 0 then that candidate is chosen. If a candidate's sum is 1, return that candidate as the answer. The candidates are:

     B (i-1), B (i-1)[2,3,4..N] ++ array [i], B (i-1)[1,3,4..N] ++ array [i]...B (i-1)[1,2..N-1] ++ array [i]

     B (i-2)[2,3,4..N] ++ array [i], B (i-2)[1,3,4..N] ++ array [i]...B (i-2)[1,2..N-1] ++ array [i]

     ...

     B (N)[2,3,4..N] ++ array [i], B (N)[1,3,4..N] ++ array [i]...B (N)[1,2..N-1] ++ array [i]

Note that for the part of the array where the numbers are negative (in the case of ascending sort) or positive (in the case of descending sort), step 3 can be done immediately without calculations.

Output:

```
*Main> least 5 "desc" [-1000,-700,-400,-200,-100,-50,10,100,300,600,800,1200]
(10,[-1000,600,300,100,10])
(0.02 secs, 1106836 bytes)

*Main> least 5 "asc" [-1000,-700,-400,-200,-100,-50,10,100,300,600,800,1200]
(50,[300,100,-200,-100,-50])
(0.02 secs, 1097492 bytes)

*Main> main -- 10000 random numbers ranging from -100000 to 100000
(1,[-106,4,-40,74,69])
(1.77 secs, 108964888 bytes)
```

Code:

```
import Data.Map (fromList, insert, (!))
import Data.List (minimumBy,tails,sort)
import Control.Monad.Random hiding (fromList)

array = [-1000,-700,-400,-200,-100,-50,10,100,300,600,800,1200]

least n rev arr = comb (fromList listStart) [fst (last listStart) + 1..m]
 where
  m = length arr
  r = if rev == "asc" then False else True
  sorted = (if r then reverse else id) (sort arr)
  listStart = if null lStart 
                 then [(n,(sum $ take n sorted,take n sorted))] 
                 else lStart
  lStart = zip [n..] 
         . takeWhile (all (if r then (>0) else (<0)) . snd) 
         . foldr (\a b -> let c = take n (drop a sorted) in (sum c,c) : b) [] 
         $ [0..]
  s = fromList (zip [1..] sorted)
  comb list [] = list ! m
  comb list (i:is)
    | fst (list ! (i-1)) == 1 = list ! (i-1)
    | otherwise              = comb updatedMap is 
   where updatedMap = insert i bestCandidate list 
         bestCandidate = comb' (list!(i - 1)) [i - 1,i - 2..n] where
           comb' best []     = best
           comb' best (j:js)
             | fst best == 1 = best
             | otherwise     =    
                 let s' = map (\x -> (sum x,x))
                        . (take n . map (take (n - 1)) . tails . cycle) 
                        $ snd (list!j)
                     t = s!i
                     candidate = minimumBy compare' (map (add t) s')
                 in comb' (minimumBy compare' [candidate,best]) js
  add x y@(a,b) = (x + a,x:b)
  compare' a@(a',_) b@(b',_) 
    | a' < 1    = if b' < 1 then compare (abs a') (abs b') else GT
    | otherwise = if b' < 1 then LT else compare a' b'

rnd :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Int
rnd = getRandomR (-100000,100000)

main = do
  values <- evalRandIO (sequence (replicate (10000) rnd))
  putStrLn (show $ least 5 "desc" values)
```

Answer (score -2):

Assumption: M is the original array

Pesudocode

```
 S = sort(M);
 R = [];
 sum = 0;
 for(i=0, i < length(S); i++){
   sum = sum + S[i];
   if(sum < 1){
     R.push(S[i]);
   }else{
     return R;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Nope, won't work. Check the array here :  

(-1000,-700,-400,-200,-100,-50,10,100,300,600,800,1200) 

Now I only want 5 elements, such that sum is least positive.

You are not taking the restriction into consideration that number of elements to be picked up should be 5 only !